# Go To Definition Like Functionality in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there is any *Go To Definition* like functionality in SQL SERVER which we use in Visual Studio. It's a little painful to browse and edit a SP or function. Any other quick way to edit will be appreciated.

Comment: The upcoming "Juneau" toolset for SQL Server 2012 will contain stuff like this - [read more about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394146.aspx) and there's also an [intro video from TechEd 2011 in the US here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV207)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some third-party tools will help, such as:

- redgate sql search (Free)
- redgate sql prompt (Commercial, trialware) - very good one
- others in Sql Toolbelt

Comment: It's mean there is no other quick way to edit SP in native SQL SERVER Management IDE?

Comment: Sql prompt helps to do it quickier and relatively comfortable, but if you want such a comfort as in Visual Studio c# editor - no

Comment: In Oracle PL/SQl IDe we can right click and edit an SP easily. I think this option is not available in SQL SERVER.

Comment: @user960567 try sql prompt - there is lot of options which help to do similar tasks

Comment: If using SQL Prompt, put the cursor on the object and press F12 (or use the Script as Alter option in the context menu).

Answer (score 2):

No. SQL Server objects don't fit into .net namespaces or object hierarchy

You can kind of emulate it with [Red Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/requirements) in SQL Server Management Studio. Or [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/), but neither of these are for Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 seems to have this functionality.  Tools -->  Options -->  Environment --> Keyboard -->  Edit.GoToDefinition, which should be F12.  If not, assign the key.

Comment: What does this actually do though?  I wasn't able to get this to go to a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Check out dbForge SQL complete: [link](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) - useful tool, has a trial, also free version but it doesn't contain go to definition functionality, only full version does.

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick. Type in any query window (SSMS 2016) the sp name you want to go to definition as you usually run it (i.e. exec sp_my_sp_name 1,2,...). Then type F11 to start debugging a couple of times until you get into the sp. Once you're inside, press stop button. I know this is not the best approach but at least you get to the sp definition quickly and faster than installing 3rd party tools or other solutions commented in this thread.

Regards